# how to interact joomla framwork database or classes into mobile application(Android)?

Tags: php, android, web-services, joomla

I am developing mobile application for one of our client project.They developed website in joomla. now i am developing same project in mobile(android using phonegap).

I have problem is that how can i use this joomla database classes in mobile application.
I am calling php web-services for this process. but in website they used 6-8 DBTables, How can  we use joomla framework in my application.

Comment: You probably want to add a JSON view in addition to the HTML view that they have. Then you can make your request for json instead of html and your application can render that. There is also some extensions that will manage that for you.

Comment: Well, you would need to understand Joomla DB properly, and then write SQL and output using php webservices. That should be enough I guess. Understanding Joomla DB would be something complex and sometime you would need to user complex SQL queries and PHP code. Good luck.

Comment: @Ravi, even I dont know joomla i am developing mobile application and i dont know how to execute joomla framework also.Thanks.

Comment: You already know how to develop PHP webservices, so you just need to understand Joomla DB, No need to learn everything in joomla. Just understand how they are managing your data. Then prepare relevant SLQ queries for your webservices.

Comment: Can you do @Ravi this is my end of project if you can help me out much more than its my pleasure.

Comment: Sorry, I'm quite busy because lots of projects are on deadline. I need to close everything asap and after that I've to finish my final year project as well. I'l let you know for sure whenever I come across joomla.

Answer (score 0):

You have to make your endpoints for an app. Joomla will not help you much with it and cleanest solution would be using fast framework to return desired data.

If you will use joomla for endpoints it will be slower. But in case you still want to do it:

Create a new component and call the request from phonegap with tmpl=raw parameter to get raw output.